# Why my view isn't updating, event with @State?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this EventDetailsView, with many TextFields, Pickers, etc. Previously it was working fantastically, but now, I don't know why, my view isn't responding to any changes. I can only delete it, TextFields, and Pickers are not working.

If you want to see some other file code, right down)

Here is EventDetailsView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct EventDetailsView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var calendarViewModel: CalendarViewModel
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State private var event: Event // My event that I am passing to this view
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                VStack {
                           // All the Pickers and TextFields Are here, they are bound to               the event, so I don't display them, because they are definitely not the problem.
                    }
                    
                    Button("Delete Event", role: .destructive) {
                        calendarViewModel.showingDeleteEventDialog = true
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Event Details")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button {
                            dismiss()
                        } label: {
                            Label("Back", systemImage: "chevron.left")
                                .labelStyle(.titleAndIcon)
                        }
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button("Save") {
                            calendarViewModel.changeEvent(event)
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .alert("Failed to set a Notification.", isPresented: $calendarViewModel.showingAlertErrorAlert) {
                    Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {
                        event.alert = .noAlerts
                        calendarViewModel.setNoAlerts()
                    }
                    Button("Settings") {
                        event.alert = .noAlerts
                        calendarViewModel.setNoAlerts()
                        calendarViewModel.openSettings()
                    }
                } message: {
                    Text("Please, enable notifications for this app in settings.")
                }
                
                .confirmationDialog("", isPresented: $calendarViewModel.showingDeleteEventDialog) {
                    Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
                        calendarViewModel.deleteEvent(event)
                    }
                    Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { }
                } message: {
                    Text("Are you sure you want to delete this event?")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    init(event: Event) {
        _event = State(wrappedValue: event) // Here I passing the event and creating the new State object
    }
}

struct EventDetailsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        EventDetailsView(event: Event.example)
            .environmentObject(CalendarViewModel())
    }
}
```

Also Here is Event struct:

```
struct Event: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable, Comparable {
    
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var tag: EventTags
    var startDate: Date
    var endDate: Date
    var repeatEvent: RepeatEvents
    var alert: Alerts
    var isCritical: Bool
    var sound: String
    var soundVolume: Double
    var color: EventColors.RawValue
    var background: Backgrounds
    var backgroundLocations: BackgroundLocation
    
    static let example = Event(title: "Workout", description: "We need to get strong", tag: .workout, startDate: Date(), endDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(86400), repeatEvent: .everyDay, alert: .noAlerts, isCritical: false, sound: "", soundVolume: 0.5, color: "darkGray", background: .color, backgroundLocations: BackgroundLocation.example)
    
    var stringStartDate: String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, HH:mm a"
        return formatter.string(from: startDate)
    }
    
    var stringEndDate: String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, HH:mm a"
        return formatter.string(from: endDate)
    }
    
    var stringNotificationTime: String {
        var formattedStart = ""
        var formattedEnd = ""
        
        if Calendar.current.isDate(startDate, inSameDayAs: endDate) {
            formattedStart = startDate.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened)
            formattedEnd = endDate.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened)
        } else {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, h:mm a"
            
            formattedStart = formatter.string(from: startDate)
            formattedEnd = formatter.string(from: endDate)
        }
        
        return "\(formattedStart) - \(formattedEnd)"
    }
    
    var currentTime: Double {
        let hour = Double(Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: startDate))
        
        let time = hour / 24
        return time
    }
    
    // Sorting
    static func <(lhs: Event, rhs: Event) -> Bool {
        lhs.startDate < rhs.startDate
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Event, rhs: Event) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }

    // Here is just more enums
}
```

Event got passed from my viewModel when it isn't nil.

```
.fullScreenCover(item: $calendarViewModel.selectedEvent) { event in
            EventDetailsView(event: event)
        }
```

Comment: watch Demystify SwiftUI it could be a couple of different things.

Comment: We need two pieces of additional code: What is `Event`? And how is the event updated?

Comment: You already have a Model. So, move all the logic into the model, inclusively the Event. In your view, only render plain data and send actions to the Model. Handle all logic in the model, and leverage reactive views. Strictly, you should not need  `@State` when you have a Model. The state comes from the Model.

Comment: Thanks! But do you mean Event Model or Calendar ViewModel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing data down to a child `View` struct you have 2 options. `let` for read access or `@Binding var` for write access, e.g.

```
struct EventDetailsView: View {

    @Binding var event: Event // for read/write access
    // let event: Event // if only need read access
```

However, when designing your `View` structs, you should ask yourself - what data does this View need to do its job? Thus instead of passing in the whole `Event` it would be better to only pass in the data it actually uses. I.e. in your case the detail view doesn't need all those params of the Event struct. This will improve performance of the change detection (since body will only be called when the properties of the Event actually being used change rather than any property changing) and make it easier to create Previews (since you don't need to create a whole test `Event`). This could look like this:

```
struct MyDetailView: View {
    let title: String
    @Binding var startDate: Date
```

And use it like:

```
MyDetailView(title: event.title, startDate: $event.startDate)
```

Comment: Hey @malhal, I must say you're one of the rare folks who genuinely share the correct concepts and principles of SwiftUI. I've learned more from your answers here than from other sources promoting outdated "ViewModel" approaches for SwiftUI. Just wanted to say thank you for your effort!